# Error 508 - Resource Limit Is Reached (php+mysql+jquery) site

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

There are several causes for 508 errors, such as;

- Website traffic spikes -  If your site experiences high peaks in inbound or outbound traffic it can exceed allocated resources. If this is a regular occurrence we would recommend considering an upgrade to a Virtual Dedicated Server, where no such limits are in place
- Problems in code. If there are pages on your site that have speed issues, an increase in inbound traffic or concurrent page requests can push the site over its resource limits
- Backend operations - demanding backend operations such as imports and exports can create significant load, which in addition to normal traffic can cause resource limits to be exceeded.
- Webcrawlers making a high number of requests per second. You can adjust the rate at which e.g. Google requests pages in Google Webmaster Tools.

Is there any other problem may occur this, please tell us. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**508 error**: Resource Limit Is Reached

It means that your website is hitting one or more of the hosting account’s virtual resource limits: CPU Usage, RAM Usage, I/O usage or Entry Processes.

**Why 508 error appear?**

The error message appears when the account is exceeding the allocated resources limit (CPU, RAM usage and/or the number of concurrent processes running under your cPanel account). You can check the resource usage of your account by logging into cPanel -> [Resources Usage](http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/104/) icon or in real time using [SSH](http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1016) command top -c. If the error appears too often, optimization of scripts or account upgrade to the plan with higher server resource limits will be required.

I give you some solution points which may help to solve 508 error.

**1)** Enable [CloudFlare](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1191/176/how-to-enable-cloudflare-for-your-domain-name) within *cPanel* to lower the load of your scripts on server and level of required resources.

**2)** If it is a permanent issue and the above suggestions did not help, then it is recommended to consider upgrading your hosting plan to the package with higher server resource limits.

You can also check the document root of your websites for any *error_log* files, if you find an *error_log* file, you should take a look at the recent entries and fix any errors that are reported. Optimizing your database tables (if any of your sites are *MySQL* driven) via *PHPMyAdmin* is also a good way to keep things running smoothly.

Let me know if there is any query from this.

Hope this help you well..!

Comment: AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, Thanks for reply. I will check your solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check MEMORY_LIMIT parameter from phpinfo(); function. If memory allocated is lower then resources your website needs, it can be the case and it can easily be increased by following code if your hosting provider allows override.

> ini_set('MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');

2. Common header and footer files and other commonly included files code and functions which may be utilizing more resources then your websites pages. There can be bottleneck in there too.

Comment: Thanks for reply, files and memory limit is ok