# Can i move wordpress posts into core php database specially the categories and sub categories

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Basically i have a wordpress blog .. Its showing resource limit problem or error connecting database sometime ..But all the wp-config.php is fine... If anyone have any solution .. please share with me

**or**

I have to move the wordpress site to core php database.. all the files and data can be managed except the category.. How to define the categories and sub categories as in worpress posts csv there is a category name but in php we have to take category id as a foreign key..

Please Give me the solution..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 508 - Resource Limit Is Reached (php+mysql+jquery) site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236764/error-508-resource-limit-is-reached-phpmysqljquery-site)

Comment: what is "core php database" ?

Comment: core php database means i have to make website in php (or in frameworks) not in cms.. But i want all my posts in my php database